# How can I load URL from input type="url" in to iframe src with onkeyup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onkeyup

So I would like to buid a preview section for a video embed tool.
I have a iframe and I have a input:

```
<input onkeyup="javascript:youtube();" onchange="javascript:youtube() ;vimeo(this) ;videotome(); setsrc();" id="url" required type="url" placeholder="Írd ide a videó URLjét" name="url">
<iframe id="vimeoFrame" src=""></iframe>
```

I would like to when the user click out from the input or typing, the iframe src update with input value.
I trying out this funtion, but not realy help:

```
function setsrc(){
var src = document.getElementById("url").value;

document.getElementById("videoFrame").value = '<iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;" width="730"  height="569" src="'+src+'"></iframe>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dhv145q9/) in jquery

```
function setsrc(){
    $('#vimeoFrame').attr('src', $('#url').val());
}
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: did you include jquery to your html head tag or before body tag close? I said thats a jquery not a pure javascript

Comment: Yes, but somehow I missed the closed comma from videoFrame!
Thanks for your answer, this realy lot of help for me!

Comment: Oh thats intrasted the function run but just once, ajter not refresh the iframe.